# Payment Gateway Integration with JavaScript and sapui5

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, sapui5

I have googled and scn but couldn't find any solution. I need a `javascript` based payment gateway, because i cannot use any middleware language like `java` or `php`. I got a demo app in sapui5 site [demo app](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/index.html).

It is possible only by using `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will vary depending on your location and target selling market.

You could look at these, which supports JS-only implementation:

- [Stripe](https://stripe.com/),
- [Braintree Payments](http://www.braintreepayments.com/),
- [CitrusPay](https://github.com/citruspay/open-javascript).

Alternativaly, [Spreedly](https://spreedly.com/) is a nice lib that integrates with many payment gateways.

*Note: I take no responsibility with regard to these methods fool- and bulletproofness.*